# Insert data into table using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate. I want to insert data into this hibernate entity:

```
@Entity
public class Invitation implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "invited_on")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date invitedOn;

    @Column(name = "invited_email")
    private String invitedEmail;

    @Column(name = "invitation_msg")
    private String invitationMessage;

    private Boolean status; //true:accepted || false:pending

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sent_by")
    private Person inviter;

// getters and setters
}
```

I tested this **code**:

```
public void insert()
{
    Query query = session.createQuery("insert into Invitation(invited_on, invited_email, invitation_msg, sent_by)");
    int result = query.executeUpdate();
}
```

What is the proper way to insert data? How I should create session Object?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/quickstart/html_single/#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic-entity

Comment: hi Peter, I suggest you to read more documents from hibernate. You need more stuff, like gettting sessionFactory, define transactions, define database connection,.... get a basic example from internet.

Comment: I added mapping file. I only need to make insert statement

Answer (score 2):

use this in the main class it works to insert data into table:

```
    Users user = new Users();
    user.setUid(1);
    user.setUfname("firstname");
    user.setUlname("Lastname");

    Configuration config = new Configuration()
       .configure()
       .addAnnotatedClass(Users.class);

    ServiceRegistry reg = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
       .applySettings(config.getProperties())
       .buildServiceRegistry();

    SessionFactory sf = config.buildSessionFactory(reg);
    Session session = sf.openSession();

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);

    tx.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have Hibernate and it's tools **USE THEM!!!**

---

**DISCLAIMER:**

- Example took from [**HERE**](http://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-insert-query-tutorial/)
- code written *on the fly!!*
- I didnt use `status` attribute because is not mapped!

---

```
// don't need if you already got a session
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

// start transaction
session.beginTransaction();

// create invitation Object
Invitation inv = new Invitation();
inv.setId(1L);
inv.setInvitedOn(new java.util.Date());
inv.setInvitedEmail("yo@yo.com");
inv.setInvitationMessage("come on!!!");
inv.setInviter(new Person("inviter"));  // hey! this is not valid for sure! :)

// Save the invitation to database
session.save(inv);

// Commit the transaction
session.getTransaction().commit();
```